# Why small screens with high pixel density are rendering wrong media query?

Tags: css, media-queries, resolution, screen-resolution, retina-display

I came across a strange problem while I was testing a simple webpage made in webflow, for responsiveness. Now this is not a webflow question, but I think the problem has something to do with the resolution, physical screen size and pixel density. Just it's not clear to me what is happening.
So there were 3 media queries. One for mobile/iPad (we will ignore them since they worked as expected), laptop screen(1280 to 1024px) and large desktop screen (equal to or above 1920). I styled the site on 1920 and the chrome Dev tool also rendered it for lower and higher screens as I expected. But when the site was viewed in a MacBook whose resolution is much higher than 1920 but the physical screen size is much smaller than a traditional monitor, rendered the media query styled for laptops. I expected with its high resolution, it will display the highest media query.
Why this has happened and how to get around this? Or this is actually okay and no fix is needed?

Comment: You might be missing — `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` — if not, you should focus less on specific sets of breakpoints ("1280 to 1024") and more on where if anywhere your layout breaks ("this layout breaks at FOO specific width").

Comment: Did you try using (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) or (min-resolution: 192dpi), your problem looks like on retina displays

Comment: It is not possible to test your page on all bfowsers,/ OS / platform combinations, so always use `@media (min-width: ...px)` and `@media (max-width: ...px)` . Do not use the `device-width` breakpoints unless you have very specific "device related" elements in your page.

Comment: Is there possibly some confusion between device pixels and CSS pixels here? A  device may have a high resolution screen (lots of physical pixels, dots of light) but may use say 4 of these for 1 CSS pixel so its media width may be only 1024px for example in CSS terms.